# Remove frames in pyplot

Tags: python, matplotlib

How to remove remove borders in pyplot image?
I tried couple of approaches but none of them seemed to work fine for me.
It is crucial for me too keep custom axis, but I would like to move them to absolute top/right/left/bottom, so borders are invisible.

[Generated image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ta0pb.png)

[How it should look like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dX2sl.png)

```
def draw(screen, palette, figures, output):
    my_dpi = 100

    size = plt.rcParams["figure.figsize"]

    size[0] = screen.height / my_dpi
    size[1] = screen.width / my_dpi

    plt.rcParams['figure.facecolor'] = screen.bg_color.code

    fig, ax = plt.subplots()
    plt.axis([0, screen.height, 0, screen.width])
    plt.axis('off')

    for figure in figures:
        col = figure.color
        if not col:
            col = screen.fg_color

        # --- #

        elif isinstance(figure, Circle):
            shape = plt.Circle((figure.point.x, figure.point.y), figure.radius, color=col.code, clip_on=True)
            ax.add_patch(shape)

        # --- #

    fig.show()
    if output:
        fig.savefig(output, facecolor=fig.get_facecolor(), bbox_inches='tight', pad_inches=0)


import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
```

Runnable example:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def draw():
    my_dpi = 100
    height = 600
    width = 800
    size = plt.rcParams["figure.figsize"]

    size[0] = height / my_dpi
    size[1] = width / my_dpi

    plt.rcParams['figure.facecolor'] = "#2c3e50"

    fig, ax = plt.subplots()
    plt.axis([0, height, 0, width])

    plt.axis('off')

    shape = plt.Circle((40, 40), 40, color="#e67e22", clip_on=True)
    ax.add_patch(shape)

    shape = plt.Circle((600, 800), 100, color="#e67e22", clip_on=True)
    ax.add_patch(shape)

    fig.show()
    fig.savefig("./shape.png", facecolor=fig.get_facecolor(), bbox_inches='tight', pad_inches=0)
```

Comment: Try removing the margins? `ax.margins(0,0)`

Comment: @DavidG well nothing happened

Comment: Ok, could you provide a [MCVE] so that we can run the code and reproduce your issue?

Comment: @DavidG okay done, I added runnable example above

Answer (score 0):

One solution is to manually set the whitespace between the axes and the edge of the figure using [`plt.subplots_adjust`](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.subplots_adjust.html) and setting everything to either 0 or 1 (depending on what argument it is). You also need to remove the arguments that modify the figure parameters in your call to `fig.savefig` as they will overwright the `plt.subplots_adjust` parameters that were set earlier.

Using your example:

```
def draw():
    my_dpi = 100
    height = 600
    width = 800
    size = plt.rcParams["figure.figsize"]

    size[0] = height / my_dpi
    size[1] = width / my_dpi

    plt.rcParams['figure.facecolor'] = "#2c3e50"

    fig, ax = plt.subplots()
    plt.axis([0, height, 0, width])

    plt.axis('off')

    shape = plt.Circle((40, 40), 40, color="#e67e22", clip_on=True)
    ax.add_patch(shape)

    shape = plt.Circle((600, 800), 100, color="#e67e22", clip_on=True)
    ax.add_patch(shape)

    plt.subplots_adjust(left=0, right=1, top=1, bottom=0)
    fig.savefig("./shape.png", facecolor=fig.get_facecolor())

    plt.show()

draw()
```

Comment: I wonder if there is sth wrong with library installed on my computer because even with your edit i get same result, but i don't think so, i have newest release installed

Comment: Hmm, ok so using `plt.show()` gives the correct figure. But _saving_ the figure still gives the same result...

Comment: @logx I realised what was wrong. I've updated my answer

Comment: okay, after your newest update saving figure gives correct output but `plt.show()` is still wrong xD

Comment: If you run the exact code from the answer the window that pops up is wrong? What version of matplotlib are you using?

Comment: Yup i copied your code and this is the result: https://imgur.com/wgDn9oa version: 2.2.2

Comment: Strange. Possibly to do with pycharm (looks like what you're using). What matplotlib backend are you using?

Comment: backend      : TkAgg